# Return data from subquery

Tags: mysql

Coming from the world of desktop databases and need some advice about SELECT query used in a PHP file.

Getting really confused about JOINS which is what I probably need to get the following to work.

I have the following query (to extract data from a MySQL database):

```
SELECT  mem_id, firstname, lastname FROM memberdetails 
WHERE mem_id in (select mem_id from classmember   
WHERE class_id= " . $classid . ") 
ORDER BY lastname, firstname ASC
```

which returns the expected dataset.

The program then loops through the returned data and for each row there is a subsequent query:

```
SELECT group_id FROM `classmember` 
WHERE (`mem_id`= '$memid' AND `class_id`= '$classid')
```

I would think there should be a way to combine this into the first query to return a data set ordered by group_id, lastname, firstname, mem_id and thus save the subsequent query (and further manipulation that isn't shown here). However I can't seen to get this to work.

Comment: Apologies if it offended you - it's an extract from a PHP file   which explains the  `mem_id`= '$memid' AND `class_id`= '$classid'- I have excluded everything that isn't relevant to the question as it is only the query that needs sorting out.

Comment: Do not worry about offending me, I just wanted to direct you to the right way to ask in SO

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, that could be consolidated into one query, using join.

This should do it:

```
SELECT  
    md.mem_id, 
    md.firstname, 
    md.lastname,
    cm.group_id 
FROM 
    memberdetails AS md
INNER JOIN
    classmember AS cm 
    ON cm.mem_id = md.mem_id
WHERE 
    cm.class_id = ?
ORDER BY 
    cm.group_id, md.lastname, md.firstname, md.mem_id ASC
```

It's untested so please comment if something doesn't work/looks wrong.

**Note:** As you can see, I've used `?` instead of the PHP variable. That's because you should use prepared statements with placeholders instead of injecting variables directly into your queries.

You can read more about prepared statements in the PHP manual:

- [Using mysqli](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)
- [Using PDO](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php)

To learn more about join's, you can read the following article:

- [MySQL Join Made Easy For Beginners](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-join/)

Comment: Thanks for the reply - have amended the code to use your suggestion and get an error "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'AS md INNER JOIN classmember AS cm ON cm.mem_id = md.mem_id WHERE cm.class_id =9' at line 1"

Comment: @OldGuy - Can you echo the complete query before you execute it and post it here?

Comment: Hi Magnus - It does work ok - I had not left a space between the FROM and memberdetails, and I just did not see it! - Many thanbks for your help and the link to the MySQL Joins tutorial.